# User profile cannot be loaded and pin is disabled

Tags: windows-11, user-profiles, reset, pin

I was doing a factory reset on my computer, when everything was finished I get this error when I try to log in:

> User profile cannot be loaded

And here's what I've tried:

1. I've tried to start the computer on safe mode to then go to serviced and fix the issue from there. This did not work for me, since I have another error saying that due to security policies my pin have been disabled, from the start menu, when I try to set up a new pin, it gets me the user cannot be loaded error, so I am kind of a loop.
2. I tried to install windows from a USB drive to start fresh, but when I do that, it says that bitlocker needs to be disabled from the panel control, which I don't know how I will do since I am not able to log in the computer.
3. I have also tried to go the services menu from the command line, but this has not worked at all.

Comment: You mean that the disk is bitlocked and you don't have the key?

Comment: No, I have the key, but when I try to install windows on the drive it says that the bitlocker is in the disk therefore I cannot install, and to deactive bitlocker it says I need to go to control panel which is not possible since I cannot log in from the first place.